# Нужно регулярное выражение для проверки переменной на адрес сайта

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

надо проверить существует ли в переменной `href` адрес сайта `'http://ru.stackoverflow.com'`

```
href = 'http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
```

Comment: а нужна именно регулярка или просто проверить наличие строки в строке? тогда так `if 'http://ru.stackoverflow.com' in your_var: ...`

Comment: нужна регулярка , в переменой может храниться ссылка на любою страницу , а нужно проверить лишь сайт есть он в этой ссылке или нет `ru.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: мой код выше должен решать эту задачу. Даже если там будет ссылка и немного текста.

Comment: да, заработало, спасибо)

Comment: можно как-то записать если НЕТ такой ссылки, то... или лучше написать просто `else` ?

Comment: Вы не поверите, но это пишется очень просто - `if "str" not in "other str":`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сформируем полный ответ.

Проверить наличие одной строки в другой

```
s = 'tt'
st = 'testtest'
if s in st:
  print "входит"
```

проверить на "не входит"

```
s = 'tb'
st = 'testtest'
if s not in st:
  print "не входит"
```

Проверить, начинается ли строка с заданой

```
s = 'te'
st = 'testtest'
if st.startswith(s):
  print "начинается с"
```